# Summing Duration Format with QUERY

Tags: google-sheets

I want to sum the `begin` and `end` with the `QUERY` function, to be able to subtract them, see table:

```
day       |   begin   |    end     |
-----------------------------------|
monday    |  9:00:00  |  13:00:00  |
tuesday   |  9:00:00  |  14:00:00  |
wednesday |  9:00:00  |  12:00:00  |
```

I was only able to perform a summation, by setting the format of the time notation to `NUMBER`.

How can I sum a time notation (duration) in the new Google Spreadsheet with the `QUERY` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, there is no straightforward way of calculating time differences inside a Sheets QUERY clause. The best that I can think of is to convert the time to a serial value (using the [hour and minute scalar functions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar_functions)), perform the difference calculation, and format the resulting column as time:

`=QUERY(A:C,"select A, hour(C)/24+minute(C)/1440-hour(B)/24-minute(B)/1440 label hour(C)/24+minute(C)/1440-hour(B)/24-minute(B)/1440 'Difference'",1)`